# How to get multiple objects returned from web API and parse it correctly in angular

Tags: angular

I was trying to get multiple objects returned from API.

Initially, The API returns a ParsedSampleMetadata array and the code works well.

```
  public class ParsedSampleMetadata {
        public string ExperimentID { get; set; }
        public string ExperimentType { get; set; }
        public string SampleID { get; set; }
        public string SubjectID { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string ConditionTypeMerged { get; set; }
        public string ConditionValueMerged { get; set; }
   }

 public async Task<ActionResult<ParsedSampleMetadata[]>> UploadExpResultFile() {
      
      // do my stuff       
      
      ParsedSampleMetadata[] r = GetSampleMeta();
      return Ok(r);
}
```

In angular service

```
postResultFile(fileToUpload: File, exp:Experiment, param: ParseExpFileParam) {
    const delim="||||";
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', fileToUpload, fileToUpload.name);
    //formData.append('dataType', dataType);
    formData.append('expType', exp.Type);
    formData.append('expID', exp.ID);

    return this.http.post<ParsedSampleMetadata[]>(this.rootURL + "/FileUpload/ExpResult", formData);
  }
```

In angular component

```
onSumbit(){
      this.fileUploadService.postResultFile(this.fileToUpload, this.existingExpList[this.selectedExpIdx], this.param).subscribe(
        data => {
          console.log(data);
          this.hasdata = true;
          this.tableDataSource1.data = data
          this.changeDetectorRefs.detectChanges();
        },error => {
          this.hasdata = false;
          this.openDialog("Failed to parse result file: " + error.message);
        });
    }
```

After that, I was trying to return multiple objects from API, thus create a wrapper class ParsedExpData which contains both parsedSampleMetadata array and a string log as below

```
 public class ParsedExpData
{
    public ParsedSampleMetadata[] sampleMeta;
    public string log;

    public ParsedExpData(ParsedSampleMetadata[] sm, string l)
    {
        sampleMeta = sm;
        log = l;
    }
 }
```

and changed my API controller:

```
 public async Task<ActionResult<ParsedExpData>> UploadExpResultFile() {
      
      // do my stuff       
      ParsedSampleMetadata[] psm = GetSampleMeta();
      string log = ReadLog();
      ParsedExpData r = new ParsedExpData(psm.ToArray(), log);
      return Ok(r);
}
```

and also changed my angular part accordingly

```
    export class ParsedExpData {
        sampleMeta: ParsedSampleMetadata[];
        log: string;
    }

  postResultFile(fileToUpload: File, exp:Experiment, param: ParseExpFileParam) {
    const delim="||||";
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', fileToUpload, fileToUpload.name);
    //formData.append('dataType', dataType);
    formData.append('expType', exp.Type);
    formData.append('expID', exp.ID);
    return this.http.post<ParsedExpData>(this.rootURL + "/FileUpload/ExpResult", formData);
  }

onSumbit(){
        this.fileUploadService.postResultFile(this.fileToUpload, this.existingExpList[this.selectedExpIdx], this.param)
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          this.hasdata = true;
          this.tableDataSource1.data = data.sampleMeta   // this line pops error, d.sampleMeta is not defined
          this.changeDetectorRefs.detectChanges();
        },error => {
          this.hasdata = false;
          this.openDialog("Failed to parse result file: " + error.message);
        });
  }
```

Now I get undefined object error, seems data in subscribe did not catch anything. But the API does return data as I debug into it (screenshot attached). Did I miss anything in my code? Thanks

[image]

Comment: You should do `console.log(data)` in your subscribe, to verify the received data shape.

Comment: Your error indicates that the data value passed from your fileUploadService is retuning nothing, therefore it is undefined. Yoy can share the code for your actual api code and possibly a log of the service request for us to better answer your question

Comment: Thank you both. I edited my post to clarify my question.